# Javascript: How do I allow a loop to change an id?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

This is my block of code.

```
var events = new Array(4);

for (var j=3; j<events.length; j++){
    events[j];
    aA.setAttribute('href', '#events(j)');    
}
```

I wish to change events(j) to 3, and allow it to have an increment of 1, after the function is called. The problem is, the   'j'   in   #events(j)    is being read as a text character and won't insert it as a number. How can I change my code to solve this problem?

Comment: aA.setAttribute('href', '#events(' + j + ')');

Comment: And why a loop at all if you're only changing the last element in the array?

Comment: I don't understand why you have `events[j]` or what `aA` is, maybe you mean `events[j].setAttribute('href', '#events('+j+')');` ? Also this isn't changing an `ID`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve here but if you want to make the `j` dynamic in  `event()` call you should concatenate the variable with string using plus `+` sign, because as it's now (wraped by quotes) it will be concedered as string `j` :

```
aA.setAttribute('href', '#events('+j+')');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`events[j];` is a blank statement here; it does absolutely nothing. You are reading a value in array but not doing anything with it.

`'#events(j)'` is interpreted as a string; note the quotes around it. To use the value of `j` instead of the letter, you need to move it outside the string and concatenate them, this way:

```
aA.setAttribute('href', '#events(' + j + ')'); // The string '#events(', then the value of j, then a closing brace
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is changing the `href` of an element to match the number of the last index of your array, you can remove the for loop and replace it with a single line of code:

```
var events = new Array(4);

aA.setAttribute('href', '#events(' + events.length - 1 + ')');
```